# how do I prepend a string to stdin in the command line?

Tags: command-line

This is probably pretty basic, but I'm struggling with the command line. Suppose I want to turn a markdown file myDoc.md to a pdf file. [Markedjs](https://marked.js.org/) provides a command line tool to convert markdown to html, and wkhtmltopdf can convert html to pdf, so I have the command

```
marked myDoc.md | wkhtmltopdf - myDoc.pdf
```

That works, it generates the pdf. But the pdf is pretty ugly, I want to prepend a style section to the html before passing it to wkhtmltopdf. Yes I could put the style section in the markdown document, but I don't want to pollute the markup with this. I want to use marked to generate html, then prepend a style section, then feed that to wkhtmltopdf, without any intermediate files to clean up. Something like this pseudo code

```
myStyle="<style>
*{
    font-family: arial;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>"
marked myDoc.md | concatenatestrings myStyle - | wkhtmltopdf - myDoc.pdf
```

but where I'm having trouble is I don't know how to handle the multiline string for `myStyle` and finding something that does what the hypothetical `concatenatestrings` command does, taking a string from stdin, prepend myStyle, and output to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template file, then use a subshell to output the template and output of `marked myDoc.md` to stdout, then pipe the results to the rest of your chain.

So, let us create the template file...

`template.html`

```
<style>
*{
    font-family: arial;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

...and use it

```sh
$ (cat template.html && marked myDoc.md) | wkhtmltopdf - myDoc.pdf
```

I haven't tested this with your command (I don't want to install `marked` just to test it), but have tested it with the following...

```sh
$ (echo ree && echo cola) | cat
ree
cola
```